# How to calculate the total time a projectile is in the air?

Tags: physics

A ball is thrown vertically upward with an initial speed of 9.80 meters per second.
What is the maximum height the ball will reach?

I need to find the distance (d). But I need the time. How do I calculate the time it will be in the air with a kinematics equation?

Comment: Use conservation of energy to compute this distance directly, without first finding the flight time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the equations below

$$0-v=-gt$$

$$d=vt-\frac 12gt^2$$

The first equation finds the time for gravity to decelerate the speed to zero at the highest point, while the second equation is the distance formula.

Then, eliminate time $t$ to get the distance,

$$d=\frac{v^2}{2g}$$